# find all combinations that have the same sum more efficiently

Tags: c++, combinations

I want to find all combinations of four numbers in the range -n to n which added up to zeros. Is there any efficient algorithms to solve this problems?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, j, k, l;
    int size = 20;

    for (i = -size; i <= size; i++)
    {
        for (j = -size; j <= size; j++)
        {
            for (k = -size; k <= size; k++)
            {
                for (l = -size; l <= size; l++)
                {
                    if (i + j + k + l == 0)
                    {
                        cout << i << " " << j << " " << " " << k << " " << l << endl;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Yes, this kind of problem is usually solved with some form of dynamic programming. I would say that this question belongs to https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is it a np hard problem?

Comment: you dont have to consider all numbers positive or all numbers negative

Comment: @learning_cpp In what sense a np hard? It's not a decision problem. I would guess that the number of combinations might be an exponential function of _n_ . So no, there cannot be polynomial solution.

Comment: @Quimby you are right so it seems the problems is expensive to solve in nature

Comment: It can't be exponential in `n` -- there are only `(2n+1)^4` possible combinations to check.

Comment: If you just want to know how many such combinations there are, then you can do that in constant time, once you have worked out the appropriate polynomial. If you need to know all solutions explicitly, then there are `O(n^3)` of them, so simply storing them or outputting them requires `O(n^3)` time. And finding them also takes `O(n^3)` time, as PeteBlacker's answer shows, so `O(n^3)` is both an upper bound and a lower bound.

Comment: So it already finished in polynomial time. Can this problem be solved using dynamic programming?

Comment: @learning_cpp Problem of getting all combination cannot be solved faster because number of combinations is O(n^3). But  problem of counting combinaiton might be performed faster-  in linear time or perhaps in O(1) (with closed formula)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my code, and comments .
Algorithm efficiency is O(N^3), and total number of solutions is also O(N^3).

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>


int main(){
      int size = 20;
       for(int a = -size; a <= size; ++a){
            for(int b = -size; b <= size; ++b ) {
                 int c_min, c_max, d, c;
                 //1.  a + b + c +d = 0.
                 //2.  d = -(a+b+c)   
                 //3.   -size <= d <= size
                 //4.  -size <= -(a+b+c) <= size
                 //5.  size >= a +b + c >= -size
                 //6.  -size - (a+b) <= c <= size - (a+b)
                 //7. but,    -size <= c <= size.
                c_min = std::max(-size, -size - (a+b) ) ;
                c_max = std::min(size, size - (a+b) ) ;
                for(c = c_min ; c <= c_max; ++c){
                      d = -(a+b+c);
                      printf("a = %d b = %d  c = %d  d= %d\n", a,b,c,d);                          
                }
            }
       }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably many methods to optimise this algorithm, but here are a couple of simple ones.

Firstly you don't need the final loop through the numbers at all:

```
for (l = -size; l <= size; l++)
    ...
```

This is because the first three numbers have been defined now, therefore there is only one possible number that can make all 4 add up to zero. All you have to do is find out what that number is and check if it is within the range -n to +n.

```
int l = 0 - (i+j+k);
if (-l >= -size && l <= size)
     ....
```

Secondly the third loop can be shortened in many cases, for example if i and j are both -size then the only possible value of k which can result in all four numbers adding up-to zero is +size. Using this idea we can put additional bounds on this loop, shortening it in a considerable number of cases.

These two optimisation should result in a very significant speed up for this algorithm.

Comment: That is smart improvement !But can  this problem be solved in polynomial time?  Suppose I have bigger size and deeper loop. I encounter this problem when intergraing a function in fourier space

Comment: There are almost certainly quicker ways of doing this thinking about it. Starting with the simple case of two numbers the set of solutions are on a line x+y=0. Three numbers define a plane and four numbers define a hyper-plane. You should be able to calculate the intersection of this hyper-plane with the origin aligned hyper-cube which limits your input. You should be able to iterate across the hyper-plane with three loops, generating solutions on every time.